# Как сохранить незавершенные изменения проекта на удаленном репозитории, не делая коммита в рабочую ветку?

Tags: git, git-commit

На работе я делаю какие-нибудь изменения в проекте, например, новый функционал, я его не допилил и поэтому не хочу заливать не рабочую версию в виде коммита, но хочу отправить временные изменения на сервер, затем доработать их из дома. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@krasnodar95](/users/23616/krasnodar95) в виде ветки feature-x, которую потом можно благополучно выпилить из репы.

Comment: А со stash тут никак не намудрить? Можно ли как-то передать stash на удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: stash локальный, в этом его смысл. Иначе чем бы он отличался от обычной ветки?

Comment: Понял, спасибо.